# Is There A Way I Can Debug An GLSL Shader?

Tags: opengl, graphics, profiling, glsl

Is there a way i can debug a glsl shader? including like breakpoints and data tracking

i seen simple ones that let me see what shaders make my shade programs but nothing i can put break points in.

I need to check out values of matrices and just throwing a glFragColor will not work since there's so many values to be compared and checked.

is there a simple way of doing this? besides me just writing down what values i think i might have and doing my math out else where.

it's really annoying when I'm trying to understand all of OpenGL and knowing how to navigate around DirectX. I can see why some people get scared away from OpenGL when resources get hard to find.

Comment: What version of OpenGL are you targeting? Forget about "breakpoints" in normal shaders, the GPU runs asynchronously with the CPU and does not have/expose the necessary interrupt logic to implement a breakpoint without using a vendor-specific tool of some sort. Furthermore, shaders run in parallel (massively). You can force a shader to stall with memory barriers in GL4, and you might be able to investigate the output using Shader Storage Buffers / Image Load/Store / Transform Feedback / etc. But all of these things require a certain version of GL and a thorough understanding of GLSL in general.

Comment: im using 3.3 and up for now

Comment: Transform Feedback is probably your best bet in that case. There was once a tool `glslDevil` that provided a lot of capabilities (except for run-time breakpoints) that you described, and it was built around transform feedback. The tool still exists, but it has not been updated and rarely works with modern GL implementations / shaders. Transform Feedback will let you get output from the vertex/geometry stages in 3.3 and as you know, for fragment shader debugging you are probably going to have to rely on fragment data output..

Comment: dang. sounds like who ever makes that amazing glsl tool will be famous haha. I'll look into TransformFeedback. i might need to find me an OpenGL Render Programmer if all fails so he can take at my code i guess..

Comment: You might want to investigate nvidia parallel nsight tools.  I think to debug you need a 2 card setup (nvidia) of some kind and I'm not sure if it works for OpenGL.

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/content/launching-nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition-30-final-opengl-debugging-and-kepler-gk110

Answer (score 0):

According to the development updates for NVIDIA Nsight, they recently added features for GLSL debugging (https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition-3_0-new-features). I would look there first. Also glslDevil (http://www.vis.uni-stuttgart.de/glsldevil/index.html) looks good. I haven't tried either program myself, so can't give first hand experience about quality. I have been impressed by NVIDIA's support for debugging in CUDA though, so have high expectations.

Comment: glsl devil wont support anything recent as releases were loooog time ago.